# Unable to assign an object with sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I try to assign an object for further handling with jQuery but it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
$('.var').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this));
  sessionStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify($(this)));
  console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('object')));
}
```

Both console logs don't have the same value. Why?

Second example:

```
$('.var').on('click', function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify($(this)));
  var item = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('object'));
  item.addClass('not-work');  //does not work
  $(this).addClass('work');   //works
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

What am I doing wrong with sessionStorage().

Comment: which object has 'var' class? are you trying to storage an element?

Comment: You won't be able to extract specific types of objects from a string with `JSON.parse`. In your second example, `item` is plain object, not jQuery one. There are many solutions to that. One possible is giving all the items to be handled some specific identifiers, storing those identifiers instead, then using them to look-up a specific DOM node.

Comment: I wonder how you got `JSON.stringify` stringify a DOM object without throwing.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.stringify strips methods from the stringified object, because valid JSON does not include functions.

Example:

```
var obj = {
prop: 5,
method: function() {}
};

JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Result: `"{"prop":5}"`

Answer (score 0):

[@Ori Drori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101979/566092) explains the first example.

In the second example, you get the DOM element (jquery wrapped), convert it to a `string!` and save in the sessionStorage.

And then get this `string` out of sessionStorage, do `JSON.parse` in hope of getting the DOM element, but instead you'll get a javascript object which is certainly not an element in the DOM tree (as I believe you're expecting) & hence, calling `.addClass` on it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm referring the second example and it's not a DOM element when we get it out of sessionStorage!

Comment: Funny, because I read `"In the second example, you get the DOM element"`

Comment: Instead of yelling, try reading my comment again... I'm saying the original object is the DOM element in **both** cases, not just the second one. And I know very well what comes back from the session storage...

Comment: read thrice and also the second example, still unable to see it from your context, not sure what you mean by original object and what cases are you referring to. Also, I didn't meant to be strict, sorry if you found it yelling.

Comment: @coding_idiot - thanks for the addition - missed the 2nd example as it was edited in.